# How to customize search bar in navigation bar in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am try to add search bar in navigation bar in both Xamarin.android and Xamarin.Ios. I have tried the below post it's working ' but I want to customise the searchbar text color and search bar image in that. Can you please suggest any idea.

I am tried link : https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/xamarin-forms-contentpage-searchbar-navigation-bar-vipin-mathews

[image]

When I apply above link code I am getting navigation bar like this and when user click on search image, search bar will be appear in navigation bar. In the above navigation bar dot's image is a toolbar images set order is 'Primary'. My requirement is show search image first then after showing the toolbar image, exactly swap the position's of search image too bar image in the above image. How can I achieve that.

Comment: i've done the same tutorial than you but i have TWO problems. The first is that the cursos is not showing when i click on the SeachBar. and the MAIN one is that when i press back button to return to SearchPage, the navigationview is not there. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You use the Priority property of the ToolbarItem to define the left to right order, not the Ordering property. I know, not confusing at all!

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Name="SearchItem" Icon="search.png" Priority="0" />
    <ToolbarItem Name="MoreItem" Icon="more.png" Priority="1" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

[Read this great blog post about the Xamarin Forms Toolbar for more details](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-toolbar/)

Comment: Thanks steve, we are able to set toolbar item priorities like that but in above navigation bar search image is I am not added. due to adding search bar in  navigation bar using custom renderer as fallow the above link I am getting. can you please suggest for this. If you open the above link you can get the clarity.

Comment: Looking at the link, the nav bar is all handled via custom Android code and renderers. The toolbar items are added in the XML near the top. I think you'll have to change this if you want to add a more button then update the renderer to grab the button like it does with the search button and wire it up to code in the PCL.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this library.

[SNavigationPage](https://github.com/stormlion227/SNavigation.Forms)

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:snav="clr-namespace:Stormlion.SNavigation;assembly=Stormlion.SNavigation"
             x:Class="Test.Page1"
             >
    <snav:SNavigationPage.NavContent>
        <Grid Margin="50, 0, 50, 0"
              >
            <SearchBar BackgroundColor="White"
                       Placeholder="Search ..."
                       />
        </Grid>
    </snav:SNavigationPage.NavContent>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        ...
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```