# Is it possible to add <SearchBar> control to the <ToolbarItem>?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Found a lot of similar questions like
[How to customize search bar in navigation bar in Xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46702566/how-to-customize-search-bar-in-navigation-bar-in-xamarin-forms)

But these answers are all 3,4 maybe 5 years old. Is there anything up to date that allows me to add the SearchBar control to the ToolbarItem that doesn't involve writing up a renderer for your Page? and is also cross platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in [Shell SearchHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/search) that you can customize both it behavior and it appearance (you don't need a custom renderer but your app needs to be based on [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/))

[Example from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/search#create-a-searchhandler):

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Xaminals.Controls">
    <Shell.SearchHandler>
...
    </Shell.SearchHandler>
    ...
</ContentPage>
```